# Blazor Webassembly - System.AggregateException

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, client-side, blazor, webassembly

I have created a RESTapi whit standard CRUD functionality. 
I have tested all functions with postman and they work without any issues.

I am consuming these function from a client blazor project using Refit, and all functions works like a sharm except for the Delete function. When I run that, I get a System.AggregateException with the message
"One or more errors occurred. (Invalid argument: source can not be null and must have a length)".

The Delete method has a guid parameter, and everything looks the same in the code regarding create, edit and delete, but delete struggles. I am getting crazy here, can someone figure out what could be the issue?

I am using a few components (Page + List -> ListItem, and the pipeline looks like this:

1. ListItem

```cs
 <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => Delete.InvokeAsync(Item))">Delete</button>

[Parameter] public BIMObjectCategoryResponse Item { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<BIMObjectCategoryResponse> Delete { get; set; }
```

2. List

```cs
[Parameter] public IEnumerable<BIMObjectCategoryResponse> Items { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<BIMObjectCategoryResponse> Delete { get; set; }
```

3. Page

```cs
// Callback - Delete
void Delete(BIMObjectCategoryResponse item)
{
    var response = bimService.DeleteBIMObjectCategoryAsync(item.BIMObjectCategoryGUID);
}
```

Ideas?

Some more clarification, and simplification.
After testing a few of the answers and recommendations below, the problem doesnt seem to be connected to the principles of the callbacks, but to a specific method. What I did was to create one simple page running the Init function only.

```
// Initialize
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Guid guid = Guid.Parse("1e9daac1-1a3e-4eab-8e49-45c2993aba4c");

    Console.WriteLine("BeginGet");
    var response1 = await bimService.GetBIMObjectCategoryAsync(guid);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonService.GetString(response1.Content.Data));
    Console.WriteLine("EndGet");

    Console.WriteLine("BeginDelete");
    var response2 = await bimService.DeleteBIMObjectCategoryAsync(guid);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonService.GetString(response2.Content));
    Console.WriteLine("EndDelete");
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I ran debug, it showed that the call didn't reach the webapi, it fails somewere before that. I tried the same operation for get/update/create and they all ended up in the debug mode of the web api.

Comment: Henrik, you are for sure right, i have added a bit of code that is more complete. Please check it out.

Comment: Yes, I implemented the logic that you recommended but that didn't help.

Comment: Please, show complete code of the deleting method. Also, show the code of your Program.cs file. I guess the issue is related to the HttpMessagelHandler  mono is using.

Answer (score 1):

Your `async` flow is wrong, better to fix that first. The error seems to indicate that your Parent (Page) component is rendering before the child item, which is then no longer present.

Starting with the ListItem, you could probably fix it with an `await` in the `@onclick` lambda but I prefer to make the process more visible:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="DeleteItem">Delete</button>

@code {
[Parameter] public BIMObjectCategoryResponse Item { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<BIMObjectCategoryResponse> Delete { get; set; }

  async Task DeleteItem()
  {
    // maybe you need Response? 
    var response = await Delete.InvokeAsync(Item);
  }
}
```

You didn't post the handling code in the Page but that also has to properly chain the async flow.

Comment: I have added a simplified approach in the initial question. Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your Page component is something like the following, right ?

```
- A (GrandParentComponent)
   -- B (ParentComponent)
   --- C (ChildComponent)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646682/how-to-know-when-eventcallback-has-been-fired/60658943#60658943) how these components can communicate...
And apply what I do here to your Deletion action.

Note that at the end of my answer I suggest to use notifier service instead, to enable communication between the components, which I believe can be a viable solution in your case. [See here my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60675317/6152891) how to define and use a notifier service. Note that the second answer in that thread suggests to use Cascading values and parameters. This is the third way to enable communication between components. It is rather clunky and can be problematic. I never recommend it, but it is still a legitimate tool, and much used by the framework itself. When communication is between two components, event delegates are the best choice, to my mind. Otherwise, a combination of the State Pattern and Notification Pattern is the easiest, and most elegant solution, to my mind.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks,  i have added a bit of code that is more complete. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Following back on the question, I have added a bug report to this matter since it works perfectly using a standard httpclient instead of Refit. So we can close this now. Thanks for all efforts :)
/Henrik